# Issue of Exporting+Submitting an html form efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, django

I'm working on my first Django project, and I'm confused about how to send a form from the server to a user, and a filled form back to the server. (i'm using jQuery with AJAX by the way). **I want to avoid sending big chunks of html via the network**.

Right now, on the POST side, I'm using jQuery's [*serialize* method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for a submission, which accomplishes my goal of not having to send a 'big' chunk of data.

But the user is GETing the forms by fetching the html form (generated from a Django template) with no alteration to it, 'straight up'.

(I'm sorry if my question is too broad for Stack Overflow. The reason for me posting this is that I feel very confused about this general issue, and after doing some searching here and via Google, I haven't found other answers that really clear my doubts about what this issue requires):

**(Is somehow transforming the html form to a JSON string and exporting that to the user what I'm looking for? Btw, some forms will also have file uploads like pictures) If so, how should I go about doing so in my Django view using an html template, and in the user template how should I go about parsing the JSON string that the user will receive, and generate the html form, from it?**

Edit: more info: For example, in terms of the user **POST**ing the answer, serialize() ends up reducing the size of what has to be sent to the server (right?) for example here:

```
<form id="the-form">
<input name="username" type="text" value="abcd" />
<input name="password" type="password" value="pass1234" />
</form>
```

using serialize you get it down to this:

```
alert($('#the-form').serialize()); // username=abcd&password=pass1234
```

My question is if, in terms of the user **GET**ing the form, instead of the server sending the entire html code to the user, is there a more efficient way? Like the server creating some JSON string that represents the form, sends it to the user, and the user's browser creating the html form it will show, using the information contained in that JSON string the server sent to it.

Edit2: an error

Comment: It's not that the question is broad, it's that it's unclear. What "massive" chunk of HTML are you talking about? Why would the form be "massive"? Why can't you just send it to the user like any other page?

Comment: I substituted massive in the question. The user will be on a phone using mobile data. I want to save as much as possible in terms of data usage.

Comment: But I still don't understand. You need to show the form to them somehow. Why do you think there's a better way than just sending it? Why would wrapping it in JSON make it smaller?

Comment: I feel like you kind of asked me my own question. That's what I wanna know and I'm confused about. I've tried to clarify my question with an edit

Comment: you are on a wild goose chase. A very wild one

Comment: `.serialize()` doesn't do anything to "reduce" the size of the data sent to the server. It produces exactly the same data as would be sent by the normal form submission process.

Comment: Ok so now things are making a little more sense to me. I was thinking  not only that serialize would somehow reduce the size of the POST but that also maybe the same could be then done for the GET by somehow transforming the html form to JSON. I appreciate you guys clearing my confusion